# Getting my CSS modules to work on my Express app

Tags: css, express, ejs

I've been using CSS just fine on one file for some time now with my current project, but it's gotten very long and harder to manage. So now I'm looking to put my CSS into modules to make editing easier. I've never done this on an Express app, only Wordpress. I've tried to use postcss like I do with Wordpress, but it does not seem to be working at all, and I'm not really understanding the npm documents for express.

Any help would be lovely.

My app.js file

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express();
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');
var postcss = require('postcss');
var atImport = require('postcss-import');


//Post CSS congig
var css = fs.readFileSync("/Users/myname/Desktop/Lookalike/public/stylesheets/style.css", "utf8");

postcss()
    .use(atImport())
    .process(css, {
        from: "public/stylesheets/style.css"
    })
    .then(function (result) {
        var output = result.css
        console.log(output)
    })


//Mongoose config
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/lookalike", {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});

//Body parser config
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public"));


//Routes
var homeRoute = require("./routes/home");


//Require routes from other files
app.use("/", homeRoute);


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, process.env.IP, function () {
    console.log("Lookalike server has started");
});
```

The head of my header file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Lookalike</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,700" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-50oBUHEmvpQ+1lW4y57PTFmhCaXp0ML5d60M1M7uH2+nqUivzIebhndOJK28anvf" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel ="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
</head>
```

My CSS module file

```
@import "/modules/front-page";
@import "/modules/discography";
@import "/modules/follow";
@import "/modules/store";


@import "/base/baseline";
```

My file config looks something like this

```
/public
  /images
  /stylesheets
    /base
      /baseline.css
    /modules
      /fontpage.css
      /discography.css
      /follow.css
      /store.css
```

Comment: so what exactly is the issue?

Comment: My CSS file / files arent working and I'm not sure why. It all works fine when it's a single file with all my CSS in it, but once I use @import it won't work anymore.

Comment: do you get the correct output here `console.log(output)`?

Comment: I do. I get what looks like all my CSS in the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you're missing in your `postcss` is *not writing* output to your destination. Following the docs it's simple.

Note that you should either name your *input css* and *output css* differently or put them in different folders (preferred)

```
postcss()
  .use(atImport())
  .process(css, {
    from: "public/stylesheets/style.css"
  })
  .then(function (result) {
    var output = result.css
    console.log(output)
    fs.writeFileSync("/Users/myname/Desktop/Lookalike/public/stylesheets/finalstyle.css", result.css) // <-- need a different name to differentiate input css and the output from postcss
    if ( result.map ) {
      fs.writeFileSync('/Users/myname/Desktop/Lookalike/public/stylesheets/finalstyle.css.map', result.map)
    }
  });
```

You could use the `async` version of `fs.writeFileSync`. I used *sync* version to be in *sync* with the code in you've posted.